# Trying to install Expo-cli, But experiencing Error Codes like NPM Install Errors Like EACCES, AND ENOEMPTY

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo, node-modules, npm-install

I am new to react native and I am having an issue installing expo-cli, and I get two different errors depending on how I try to install expo-cli.  If I do `npm install --global expo-cli`, it gives the `EACCES` error.

This is what the problem looks like:

```
    npm install --global expo-cli
    npm ERR! code EACCES 
    npm ERR! syscall rename 
    npm ERR! path /Users/mac1/.npm-global/lib/node\_modules/expo-cli 
    npm ERR! dest /Users/mac1/.npm-global/lib/node\_modules/.expo-cli-sUcgOQ3i 
    npm ERR! errno -13 
    npm ERR! 
    npm ERR! Your cache folder contains root-owned files, due to a bug in 
    npm ERR! previous versions of npm which has since been addressed. 
    npm ERR!
    npm ERR! To permanently fix this problem, please run: 
    npm ERR!   sudo chown -R 501:20 "/Users/mac1/.npm"npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
    npm ERR!     /Users/mac1/.npm/\_logs/2021-12-28T04\_20\_03\_084Z-debug.log
```

When I input `sudo npm install expo-cli -g --unsafe-perm`, it gives an `ENOEMPTY`error like this

```
    npm ERR! code ENOTEMPTY
    npm ERR! syscall rename
    npm ERR! path /Users/mac1/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/expo-cli
    npm ERR! dest /Users/mac1/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/.expo-cli-sUcgOQ3i
    npm ERR! errno -66
    npm ERR! ENOTEMPTY: directory not empty, rename '/Users/mac1/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/expo-cli' -> '/Users/mac1/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/.expo-cli-sUcgOQ3i'
    
    npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
    npm ERR!     /Users/mac1/.npm/_logs/2021-12-29T00_39_39_814Z-debug.log
```

It is important to add that I have tried to other methods that might solve this problem like, `yarn add global expo-cli` , `sudo chown`, `npm cache clean --force`, .  But nothing has worked, I'm not sure if the methods don't work, or if I'm doing the procedure wrong.

Thank You for Your Time!

Answer (score 1):

Option 1:  I would recommend you install node js by using the nvm(node version manager). That way you can have different versions of node js installed on your system and you can easily switch versions. Then try using an earlier node version like 14 to install expo-cli

Option 2: Debug - Go through the log file, you are going to see where the error is coming from1